# One more incorrect result of CDF

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics

In 13.3.1 on Windows 10 I find

```
cdf = CDF[ TransformedDistribution[\[Xi] + 
2*\[Mu], {\[Xi] \[Distributed] 
 DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, n}], \[Mu] \[Distributed] 
 GeometricDistribution[p]}], t]
```

> `Piecewise[{{p, n > 0 && n - t < 0},  {p/(1 + n), (n == 0 && t >= 0) ||  (n > 0 && t == 0)},  {(p*(1 + Floor[t]))/(1 + n),  n > 0 && t > 0 && n - t >= 0}}, 0]`

and

```
cdf /. {n -> 5, p -> 1/2, t -> 7}
```

> `1/2`

In order to verify it by the definition of the `CDF`,

```
n = 5; p = 1/2;
Probability[\[Xi] + 2*\[Mu] <= 7, {\[Xi] \[Distributed] 
DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, n}], \[Mu] \[Distributed] 
GeometricDistribution[p]}]
```

> `41/48`

At least one of the above results is not correct. The question is: what of these is correct? I think the latter.

Comment: Random experiment would suggest `Probability` is correct, and also CDF can be correct if you set `n` and `p` beforehand. But CDF is wrong if you compute it symbolically then do the replacement afterwards. 
```With[{samp = 1000000},
  Count[
    RandomVariate[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 5}], samp] + 
     2*RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[1/2], samp]
    , x_ /; x <= 7]/samp
  ] // N``` You should report as a bug to Wolfram. It seems there are many such problems with TransformedDistribution.

Comment: @flinty: Thank you for your confirmation of the bug. BTW, `Probability[\[Xi] + 2*\[Mu] <= 
  t, {\[Xi] \[Distributed] 
   DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, n}], \[Mu] \[Distributed] 
   GeometricDistribution[p]}]` produces an answer in the terms of `DifferenceRoot`s. I think that answer can be improved.

Comment: [CASE:5091726] has been submitted by me.

Comment: @flinty:  Can you kindly present your [extended] comment as an answer, making use of `PearsonChiSquareTest`? It would also be useful for didactic purposes.

Comment: I don't have much confidence in Mathematica's symbolic distribution handling: for example `With[{d = CauchyDistribution[0, 1]}, Expectation[(X - Y)^2, {X \[Distributed] d, Y \[Distributed] d}]]` gives `-2` but (X-Y)^2 cannot be negative. Of course, we should expect a positive infinity here, or undefined, but certainly not a negative number. It leads me to believe Mathematica is not handling the singularities in the underlying integrations properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue seems to be with `DiscreteUniformDistribution` when one of the parameters is an integer and the other an undefined variable.  The following all give the correct answer:

```
CDF[TransformedDistribution[ξ + 2*μ, 
  {ξ \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 5}],
   μ \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[1/2]}], 7]
(* 41/48 *)

CDF[TransformedDistribution[ξ + 2*μ,
  {ξ \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 5}],
   μ \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[1/2]}], t] /. t -> 7
(* 41/48 *)

CDF[TransformedDistribution[ξ + 2*μ,
  {ξ \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 5}]
   μ \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[p]}], t] /. {t -> 7, p -> 1/2}
(* 41/48 *)

CDF[TransformedDistribution[ξ + 2*μ,
  {ξ \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{nmin, nmax}],
   μ \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[p]}], t] /. {t -> 7, p -> 1/2, nmax -> 5, nmin -> 0}
(* 41/48 *)
```

The following all give the wrong answer:

```
CDF[TransformedDistribution[ξ + 2*μ, 
  {ξ \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, n}],
   μ \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[p]}], t] /. {t -> 7, p -> 1/2, n -> 5}
(* 1/2 *)

CDF[TransformedDistribution[ξ + 2*μ,
  {ξ \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{nmin, 5}],
   μ \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[p]}], t] /. {t -> 7, p -> 1/2, nmin -> 0}
(* 1/2 *)

CDF[TransformedDistribution[ξ + 2*μ, 
  {ξ \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, n}],
   μ \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[p]},
  Assumptions -> n ∈ PositiveIntegers], t] /. {t -> 7, p -> 1/2, n -> 5}
(* 55/96 *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your work. It should be noticed that `CDF[TransformedDistribution[\[Xi] + 
   2*\[Mu], {\[Xi] \[Distributed] 
    DiscreteUniformDistribution[{nmin, nmax}], \[Mu] \[Distributed] 
    GeometricDistribution[p]}], t]` produced a complicated expression in terms of `DifferenceRoot`s. Can it be simplified to a closed form expression? If so, I would accept your answer.

Comment: "closed form" is in the eye of the beholder.  But applying `//FunctionExpand` gets rid of the `DifferenceRoot`.  The resulting equation doesn't look nice but can be easily implemented in other languages (R, Excel, etc.).

Comment: Thank you. I accept it as a workaround.